# winginx server software, latest version (0.6.3.1), wont start

Tags: php, debugging, winginx

been a while.

I've noticed there's been an update on Winginx server software, so i downloaded latest version last day and re-installed. Everything was fine after the install, started right after without trouble. After i re-booted my laptop, as usual, the winginx (0.6.3.1) simply would not start! It came up with this debugging window, told me the service/software stopped working and not possible to start, also told me that it searched for solutions "using windows 10 currently, so we know that's a lie"...

anyhow, anyone had same trouble before?
Regards, me.

PS: Could not find any other topic about this, so really hoping that someone can help me out here, since i love the way winginx is based with memcached and everything, makes life a lot easier. And yes i know there are other server softwares out there like XAMPP etc, but i like this one, used xampp b4 but too long and too advanced.. which is why i like the winginx :P

Thanks in advance, again! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ran into the same problem myself, I had to change a few settings.

In your main nginx.conf file under the first http block add this right before the server section:

```
server_names_hash_bucket_size 512;
```

the file is /winginx/conf/nginx.conf

next if it still fails to start check: /winginx/logs/error.log

I had this error:

```
2017/11/04 05:48:08 [error] 5452#11160: CreateFile() "C:\winginx/temp/nginx.pid" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified)
```

so I created the file manually.

then if you have VMWare Workstation installed you will get this error:

```
2017/11/04 05:49:36 [emerg] 8296#3996: bind() to 127.0.0.1:443 failed (10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions)
```

which can be fixed by:

- Edit > Preferences
- Shared VMs tab
- Disable Change port
- Enable